# Which HTML tag to use to display time?

Tags: html, semantics

I am showing current time in my web app.

I can show it in a `span` or a `div`.

But which would be semantically apt?

Comment: see this: http://html5doctor.com/the-time-element/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `<span>` nor `<div>` has any semantic meaning at all.  If you want a semantic time, use `<time>` instead.  http://microformats.org/wiki/datetime-design-pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<footer>
  <p>Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
  <p><time pubdate datetime="2012-03-01"></time></p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML  `<time>` tag. You can use this to make the time data readable by a machine. But to display the actual time you need something else, maybe Javascript voor the time of the machine of the user. Or via a server using PHP or a other language.